# Flatpak (flatpak-build) fatal error when building submodules

Tags: opensuse, fuse, flatpak, gnome-builder

Following on from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48880919/flatpak-meson-vala-not-finding-libraries-gnome-builder/48931445#48931445), when using OpenSUSE Tumbleweed I cannot get `flatpak-builder` to compile submodule dependencies.  I first noticed this issue when developing a console application within Gnome Builder using the Vala dependencies Gee and GXml.

As a test, I have installed [org.gnome.Books.json](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-apps-nightly/tree/org.gnome.Books.json) and issued the following command (as documented [here](http://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/flatpak-builder.html)):

```
$ flatpak-builder --repo=repo books-app org.gnome.Books.json
```

The outcome is the same as I observed when developing my own application, the fatal error:

```
Initializing build dir
Committing stage init to cache
Starting build of org.gnome.Books
fuse: failed to exec fusermount: Permission denied

<more stuff>

Cloning into '/home/robin/Projects-CSim/org.gnome.books/.flatpak-builder/build/gnome-online-accounts-1/telepathy-account-widgets'...
Submodule path 'telepathy-account-widgets': checked out '7d944b79961dfb6291110ceb27597a224d329b36'
error: Build directory /home/<user>/Projects/org.gnome.books/.flatpak-builder/rofiles/rofiles-D4R4cZ not initialized, use flatpak build-init
Error: module gnome-online-accounts: module gnome-online-accounts: Child process exited with code 1
```

Effectively it fails to build the very first submodule. This is the same behaviour that I observed when invoked from Gnome-Builder on my project; it downloaded but failed to build the very first submodule - in that case it was libgee-0.8.

I've double checked the Flatpak (V0.10.4) installation [here](https://flathub.org) and cannot find a solution.  I understand from the documentation that invoking `flatpak-builder` should automatically invoke `flatpak build-init`.

This is worrisome as Gnome-Builder seems be using Flatpak as the default packager.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not Flatpak.  It is a conflict between Flatpak and **fuse**.  For some reason this was not occuring with valac or meson from the command line, only Flatpak.

From [here](https://www.raditha.com/blog/archives/fuse-failed-to-exec-fusermount-permission-denied.html) we find a solution:

```
# chmod +x /usr/bin/fusermount
```

Is this a peculiarity of OpenSUSE Tumbleweed?  In any case, after making this change, Flatpak builds submodules as expected.  Magnificent!

Not sure about the security aspect of this, however - any comments would be welcomed.

Comment: On openSUSE,  `fusermount` is only executable by members oft he group `trusted` by default. The whole truth is more complicated, it depends on the permission level settings. See [here](https://forums.opensuse.org/t/sshfs-problem-fuse-failed-to-exec-fusermount-permission-denied/125981/7) for example.